# how to validate input data in access form by vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to not allow users to enter fractional values example .238 or 0.123 or 1.4,.

My code So far. 
to Validate <= 8 , If Not IsNumeric, <> 12

```
Private Sub txt_xampleqty_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 On Error GoTo errormsg
    If Len(Me.txttxt_xampleqty) <= 8 Then
        Cancel = True
        Resume Next
    Else
        If Len(Trim(Me.txt_xampleqty)) <> 12 Then
            MsgBox ("Enter Correct QTY.")
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(Trim(txt_xampleqty)) Then
        MsgBox "the entry must be a 12 number QTY "
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code without more context as to what your data looks like... Length <= 8, why? What is your question? Does this code not work? If so, what result is it giving you? Does it throw any errors? Please expand the information provided in your question.

Comment: i need to prevent  fractional values to be entry

Comment: I got that much. But why would a 12-digit number verify it's not fractional? Could you instead test to see if: `[input] = INT([input])`? Wouldn't that test to see if there's a fraction?

Comment: in real data validation this field is getting the qty for  SN  and work orders in my app, so  when my users key  > 5 digit qty no allow, <1 not allow, empty no allow, as23 not allow, but if they key 0.2 or 1.245 or 1.8 is taking the qty as valid and  that is a issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check each position in the string and see if it is numeric

```
Public Function ValidNumericValue() As Boolean
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim bValid as Boolean
bValid = True
'get Text value
s = txt_xampleqty

'loop through the entire string
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    'check to see if the character is a numeric one
    If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) = False Then
        'set the return value
        bValid = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
ValidNumericValue = bValid
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the number to an integer and see if has the same value:

```
If IsNumeric(Trim(txt_xampleqty)) Then
    if CLng(txt_xampleqty)<>CCurr(txt_xampleqty)
        MsgBox "You are not allowd users to entry fractional values example .238 or 0.123 or 1.4"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```

Comment: It seems `txt_xampleqty` will be a 12 digit number.  That is beyond the capacity of Long Integer.  For example, `CLng(100000000000)` triggers error #6, *"Overflow"*.

Comment: I modified the answer to cast to Currency. It is limited to 4 digits right of Decimal point, that should be enough for testing. I also added a text search option answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextSearch Function to search for deciml point:

```
If IsNumeric(Trim(txt_xampleqty)) Then
    if InStr(txt_xampleqty,".")<Len(txt_xampleqty) Then 
        MsgBox "You are not allowd users to entry fractional values example .238 or 0.123 or 1.4"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```